# LessCss/Sass - Access inner variables?

Tags: html, css, web, sass, less

Is it possible to access an inner variable ?

Given:

```
  .method() {
       @variable:100:
  } 

 .class {
       z-index:.method.@variable;
 }
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the exact way you're thinking, but you can achieve that result. Depending on your styles you may need to adjust things to fit this model. (LESS does a great job at resolving references regardless of the order things appear in a file, but putting dependencies above the things that call them is a helpful organization habit.)

```
.class(@x) {
    z-index: @x;
}
.method() {
    @variable: 100;
    .class(@variable);
}
```

---

Note that if you don't need to use `@variable` anywhere else inside `.method()` you can skip the declaration. That is, declare a variable if you want to do something like

```
.method() {
    @variable: 100;
    .class(@variable);
    padding-right: unit(@variable,px);
}
```

and if you don't need the variable save yourself that line:

```
.method() {
    .class(100);
    color: red;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

1. If you want to be able to pass a value to `.method`, let the mixin take an argument rather than defining the variable within the mixin. With this you can do both `.example {method(100)}` and `.example{method(200)}`.

```less
.class(@x) {
    z-index: @x;
}
.method(@x) {
    .class(@x);
}
```

2. If `.class` needs to be able to work without being passed an argument, you can provide it with a default value. Given

```less
.class(@x:100) {
    z-index: @x
}
```

`.example{.class}` will compile to the same thing as `.example{.class(100)}` would.

Comment: Well, not exactly the same thing. .class is not a method, it's a class. Also, this kind of breaks the responsibility principle. .class should take care of it self, and also won't work if you need access to for instance .method2.@anothervariable.

Comment: Sounds like there's a semantic mismatch here: LESS doesn't have a thing called "method". Can you describe the distinction you're drawing between "method" and "class"? (I may be able to nip this in the bud by saying that people sometimes find it weird that in LESS every selector is by definition a mixin.)

Comment: Again maybe semantics, because `.class` does take care of itself in the sense that `.example {.class(10)}` will work. But maybe you mean `.example {.class}` should compile to something? I've added an example of how to provide a default value so that `.class` can be used without passing it an argument. Note that there are cases where you don't need or even want a mixin to compile to anything without being called by something else (basic example: if `.class` is always called by `.method`, you'd be adding unnecessary weight to your css by including styles for a standalone `.class`).

Comment: Didn't understand from your question that you wanted to be able to use other values. I've added an example of how to let `.method` take an argument

Comment: Consider another .method, .method-2.@variable. How would class access that in your example?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, and it's tricky since I don't know how the imagined syntax works. `.method-2(@variable){.class(@variable)}`? Maybe go a level less generalized and describe the scenario?

Comment: Think of method-1, method-2 as classes and .class needs to access static properties inside those classes. This is exactly the same. The logic pertaining to method-1 should be in that method-1 class, and the logic to method-2 should be in method-2. The thing is that in less you can access inner methods but not properties, which is a downer.

Comment: I don't mean to be one of those semantics jerks, but it does make it a little confusing since there are no "methods" in LESS or CSS. There are "properties", but I think you might mean what CSS calls a "value" (e.g. in `p {color: red}`, `color` is a property and `red` is its value). This feels like an interesting question that will have an interesting answer… just still not sure what the question is ha! Can you describe the scenario? What's an actual example of what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in less and we are going no where. I told you to think of it as a static class property. That's pretty clear. What the name that each language chooses for their logic is all bullshit. It's a method by any definition and eveyone can relate to that. Mixing, class, property, variable, function, method, ... we can talk teh universal language and language here is not that important. Sorry for being a bit hard. It's just not possible in less right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand right your question but I have a solution, I hope that you find it useful:

**In Less:**

```
.method(){  
  @variable:100;
}

.method2(){  
  @variable:200;   
}

.class {
  .method();
  z-index:@variable;
 } 

.class2 {
  .method2();
  z-index:@variable;
}
```

**In SASS**

```
@function method() {
    $variable: 100;
    @return $variable;
}
@function method2() {
    $variable: 200;
    @return $variable;
}

.class {
  z-index: method();
} 

.class2 {
  z-index: method2();
}
```

**CSS output for SASS/LESS:**

```
.class {
  z-index: 100;
}

.class2 {
  z-index: 200;
}
```

Comment: Think of method-1, method-2 as classes and .class needs to access static properties inside those classes. This is exactly the same. The logic pertaining to method-1 should be in that method-1 class, and the logic to method-2 should be in method-2. The thing is that in less you can access inner methods but not properties, which is a downer.

Comment: I think there is no way to access a specific property of a class. Using maps in SASS or hashes in Stylus it is the closest I've been to achieve something similar, in Less is more difficult get the same feature. Obviously is not what you want.